# How to download file to iphone coming as byte array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

below code i use an asmx webservice to get a file as byte array and want to save it to iphone application's documents directory

the file i request is a sqlite file

and my code is :

```
-(void)getfile{


NSString* soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> <soap:Body> <GetDocument xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\"> <DocumentName>%@</DocumentName> </GetDocument></soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>", @"ErtugrulGuler"];
NSURL* theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.xxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx.asmx"];
                 NSString* msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
                 NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theUrl];
                 [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                 [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetDocument" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
                  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                  [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                  [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];
if (connect) 
{


}
else {

    NSLog(@"No Connection established");

 }
 }

  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
// so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
// Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
// also serves to clear it
downloadData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
[downloadData appendData:data];
NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data string: %@",receivedDataString);
NSLog(@"data length: %d",[data length]);
//NSLog(@"bytesWritten == %d error == %@",bytesWritten,[fileOutputStream streamError]);
 }



 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
//NSLog(@"finish loading");
 [self performSelector:@selector(downloadData:) withObject:downloadData afterDelay:0];

  }

  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// The request has failed for some reason!
// Check the error var
  }



   -(void)downloadData:(NSData*)response

  {

//NSLog(@" \n\n STRING =  %@ \n\n ",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *documentFile=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.sqlite"];

NSString  * yourAppendingText=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[yourAppendingText writeToFile:documentFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

  }
```

and this is my webservice method that returns byte array

```
[WebMethod]
public Byte[] GetDocument(string DocumentName)
{
    string strdocPath;
    strdocPath = "path" + DocumentName;

    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    int len = (int)objfilestream.Length;            
    Byte[] documentcontents  = new Byte[len];
    objfilestream.Read(documentcontents,0,len);
    objfilestream.Close();

    return documentcontents;    
}
```

this code connects successfully but i dont know how to get file with NSData and write the file to Documents Directory as .sqlite

@EDIT:
i solve something but the file i wanted to get is 53kb and my recieved data as string like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetDocumentResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

and data length : 297 so it cannot get the data i think

in asp.net i run the service and get data successfully. so there is no problem with service but maybe maxiimumrecieving size for ios could be increased? but how?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSOutputStream *fileOutputStream;
NSString *databasePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@",NSHomeDirectory(),@"database.sqlite"];
    fileOutputStream = nil;
    fileOutputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:databasePath append:NO];
    [fileOutputStream open];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

   int bytesWritten  = [fileOutputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    NSLog(@" %s bytesWritten == %d  error == %@",__FUNCTION__,bytesWritten,[fileOutputStream streamError]);
}
```

Comment: should i write the NSOutputStream to the if statement? and would you explain the connection didreceivedata delegate please? i am new to ios

Comment: NSString *urlString = @"databaseURL"
  

    if ( urlString == nil || [urlString length] <= 0){
        //urlString = kDatabaseURL;
        //NSLog(@"urlString is null");
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    request.timeoutInterval = 180;
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection; = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

Comment: i really dont understand i am so sorry :( would you edit your answer? how can i use nsurlconnection delegates and what should i write in didreceivedata delegate exactly to write the file to the documents directory and how can i know if it is finish? i am sorry really i am new to ios so i need specific answers

Comment: Once check this examples then you understand the NSUrlconncetion & delegate method implementation after use above posted code

Comment: ok thanks for helping and i edit my question now. i received data but data length is too small my data is 53kb and recieved data length 297 so i think this is a different problem